# Sonnyt Twitter feed JS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I've downloaded the jQuery Twitter feed provided by Sonnty here (https://github.com/sonnyt/Tweetie). It works perfectly for a single tweet but if the count is greater than 1 it throws the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"
It seems to be around line 115 with this the culpret: "+ tweet.retweeted_status.text".

Any ideas guys?

Kind regards
Liam

Comment: can you show a working example? because no-one can guess anything useful without seeing anything

Comment: Hey netfuel, Yes a code example would help- as it seems to work fine for me

Comment: I seem to have fixed it but I don't understand why... I changed the Twitter API information to a different user's connection details and it fixed it. If I put the secrets etc back in from my account it causes the error. Strange.